# Is it possible to auto-import multiple packages with just one import?

Tags: scala

I have some functionality that extends a `SparkContext` in a bunch of very long packages, and for the spark-shell and Zeppelin (and Jupyter...), I want the user to provide a single import-all.

So, I want that the user can do something like

```
import myext._
```

and behind the scenes, it will do

```
import something.very.long.and.clumsy.uncomfortable.to.handle.on.a.shell._
import something.different.very.long.and.clumsy.uncomfortable.to.handle.on.a.shell._
// more
```

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Or do I have to write a "helper object" like this:

```
import something.very.long.and.clumsy.uncomfortable.to.handle.on.a.shell._
import something.different.very.long.and.clumsy.uncomfortable.to.handle.on.a.shell._

package object myext {

  implicit class MyExtHelper(sc: SparkContext) {

    def somethingFromLib1 = sc.somethingFromLib1
    def somethingFromLib2 = sc.somethingFromLib2
    // more
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to provide a helper object. Note that it can include type aliases like `type Foo[A] = something.very.long.and.clumsy.uncomfortable.to.handle.on.a.shell.Foo[A]` as well as methods, implicit conversions, etc. Unfortunately, there is no way (that I know of) to provide the wildcard imports in such a way; you'll have to add members to the helper object for each member of the package you want to expose.